# String to Symbol in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

Metadata of a variable such as the docstring can be read like so: Here the function `map` is used as an example:

```
(-> cljs.core/map var meta :doc)
;= "Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of appl....
```

What would I have to do to get the same result when only having the function name and its namespace as a string (as `"cljs.core/map"`)?

Wrapping the string with the function `symbol` yielded an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

*** Clojure file ***

```
(ns myproject.macros
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defmacro doc1 [s]
  (let [sym (apply symbol (str/split s #"/"))]
      `(-> ~sym (var) (meta) :doc)))
```

*** ClojureScript file ***

```
(ns myproject.main
  (:require-macros [myproject.macros :as m]))

(prn (m/doc1 "cljs.core/inc"))
```

=>
"Returns a number one greater than num."